# Locked out by CyanogenMod 11 upgrade

Tags: cyanogenmod

I tried a CyanogenMod 11 to upgrade from 4.1.2 to 4.4 on Samsung S3 Mini i8190. When the phone rebooted, my pin no longer worked. The 3 button hard reset has never worked on my phone. This mod is supposed to have TWRP but can't get to recovery mode. I tried a few flash options for hard reset and one jacked the phone turning on and off repeatedly. I tried flashing a 4.1.2 stock ROM but the phone would endlessly reboot. Heard this was a common problem when downgrading. So went back to 4.4. I don't believe debugging was enabled, since the instructions I followed didn't say to do that. So adb shell won't work. WiFi and data transfer were disabled so Google Manager idea won't work as well.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I have at this point for recovering usability of your phone would be to boot into Download Mode and flash a full suite with ODIN.